# How to use exitwp.py build file for Octopress to migrate content from Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, octopress

I've successfully migrated my Wordpress site using `exitwp.py`. I have all of my wordpress file converted into markdown format on build directory inside exitwp directory, i'm using octopress, how I can put my Wordpress exported files into Octopress to show it on my blog based on Octopress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy all files from

`path_to_exitwp/build/jekyll/your_blog_url`

to

`path_to_octopress/source`